# Side Menu xaml Navigation Error windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm currently trying to develop a windows phone 8 app that has a Side Menu.  I've managed to load 2 different xaml pages (menuitems.xaml & mainpage.xaml).  So the problem here is that, whenever I try to click on the menu, it gives me an error as follows :-

> System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e) Unknown
>   System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.IsNonRecoverableUserException(System.Exception ex, out uint xresultValue) Unknown
>   System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName) Unknown

I've uploaded my source codes here.  I do hope that I could get some advice on how to get it done.  Thanks!

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=24BED6E1EB5E271A!110&authkey=!AFcidu4XGUa44-0&ithint=file%2c.zip

Comment: Welcome at stack overflow. In order to improve your question you should explain what control you are using. Side Menu isn't a common control is it? Next, in stead of posting a zip with all the code you should provide snippets of your code that you think is causing the error.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry my bad.  Will do that next time.  Thanks for the tips, as I'm still fairly new in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your navigation services doesn't register navigation to `MenuItems()`, in order to navigate use this

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

For consideration - it will be much easier if you use `Custom User Control` to implement Slide Menu

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Really appreciate it.  Managed to get it working.  Thank you for your recommendation for the Custom User Control.  Will look into that once I finish up with this school project of mine first :)